# Stop Arduino liquid crystal text wrapping over two lines

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

The following code scrolls the text from left to right but wraps overflowing characters onto the top line. How do I get the text to display in it's entirety, scrolling from left to right but on the bottom line only.

```c++
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup()//method used to run the code for once 
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);//LCD order
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);//Setting the cursor on LCD
  lcd.print("www.TheEngineeringProjects.comwww.TheEngineeringProjects.com");//prints on LCD
  delay(1000);//delay of 1 second
}

void loop() //used to run the code repeatedly
{
 for(int PositionCount=0;PositionCount<20; PositionCount++)//loop for scrolling the LCD text
  {
    lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();//builtin command to scroll left the text
    delay(150);// delay of 150 msec
    }


}
```

Comment: Other than truncating?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I basically want to the screen to behave like it is 16x1, I want the text to scroll on one line from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=44953.0) post on Arduino forms, setting the amount of columns to a higher amount will stop the display from overflowing to the top line.

This line:

```
lcd.begin(16, 2);//LCD order
```

Becomes:

```
lcd.begin(40, 2);//LCD order
```

This should fix the overflow onto the top line.

Comment: It's true, you do need to initialize the display with the correct number of chars and rows.